# React native Redux with Navigation issues

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, navigation

I have recently started programming in React Native and just got into Navigations and they're pretty cool and powerful. As a beginner however, I am coming across some issues. I am using Redux to manage states and I have a Navigation Stack that should only render when a logged in state is active. This is a small snippet of the code.

```
const RootStackScreen = () => (
  <RootStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
    {initialState.loggedIn ? (
      <RootStack.Screen name="Application" component={TabScreen} />
    ) : (
      <RootStack.Screen name="Authentication" component={AuthStackScreen} />
    )}
  </RootStack.Navigator>
);
```

As you can see here, I have two Screens in my RootStack, My authentication screen and then my main app screen. I am simply trying to say hey if the `loggedIn` state is true then render application otherwise render the authentication screen. The issue is, when I change the state with redux through my login page, it updates but it does not change the page. For convenience sake, I have also attached my redux initialState and reducer

```
const initialState = {
  action: "",
  loggedIn: false,
  username: null,
  isLoading: false,
  failedLogin: "",
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "USER_LOGIN_GOOD":
      return { loggedIn: true };
    case "USER_LOGIN_FAIL":
      return { failedLogin: "Login Failed, Please try again" };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I have tried saying `initialState.loggedIn` as well as just `loggedIn` but for some reason it does not update the value when it is updated through redux in another page. I have checked to make sure that the values are updating by simply printing the new value, so I know it is not a problem with updating value but only with the RootStack sensing the update.

Thank you very much! Any help will be useful as I have been pulling my hair out for this!!!

UPDATE: I am setting the state from my Login page by calling Dispatch

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    logInSuccess: () =>
      dispatch({
        type: "USER_LOGIN_GOOD",
      }),
    logInFailed: () =>
      dispatch({
        type: "USER_LOGIN_FAIL",
      }),
  };
}
```

Also I have just tried passing in the initialState into the RootStack like such

```
const RootStackScreen = (initialState) => ( CONTENT HERE )
```

But it still does not work. Again, Thank you very much

Comment: `RootStackScreen` should be getting the logged in value from props. Can you post more of the code where the `initialState` is being set for the `const RootStackScreen`?

Comment: Post have been update!

Comment: Thanks for the update, but what I'm really looking for is how the state is bound to the `RootStackScreen`. In redux, you should be setting all the values in to a store and then accessing them from your components by connecting them to the store(by hooksor HoC). Are you trying to access the `initialState` directly in your root screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this scenarios as per react navigation docs, you shouldnt do any conditions in your component where you have placed the stack navigators etc.

What the better approach is make a splash screen first, which is usually there in every app.

make it the initial route and then there do the logical computation of which page to be shown, like eg :

```
<Stack.Navigator
          initialRouteName="SplashScreen"
          >
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="SplashScreen" component={SplashScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
```

So here Splashscreen is the initial route , and in the Splashscreen you do like :

```
class SplashScreen extends .. {

...
componentDidMount(){
isLoggedIn?this.props.navigation.navigate('Home'):this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
}

}
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Ok so i tries this and it kinda worked. It would take the user to Splash then login because they're not logged in. However, the issue now is that when I update isLoggedIn from my Login screen it does not go to the home screen.

Comment: So I figured it out I just needed to manually put ```this.props.navigation.navigate("Application");``` in the Login success function. Is this a good practice?

Comment: Good that you managed it out. If you think my answer helped. You can upvote. Thanks

Comment: Could you post a link to the documentation that says conditions are a bad practice in the root navigation? According to this link https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/ it is actually ok. I would like to find out what is the best practice in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@ Nathan Belete

In the root stack, you shouldn't have an if-else statement brother. Your first initial route should be **Authentication**. I think you could update it to like this.

```
const RootStackScreen = () => (
  <RootStack.Navigator headerMode="none" initialRouteName="Authentication">
      <RootStack.Screen name="Application" component={TabScreen} />
      <RootStack.Screen name="Authentication" component={AuthStackScreen} />
    )}
  </RootStack.Navigator>
);
```

then in the file **AuthStackScreen.js** you should handle logic to check whether the user is already login or not. here is the sample code:

```
import {useDispatch, useSelector, useStore} from 'react-redux'

export const SignInScreen = ({navigation}: SignInProps): ReactElement => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const appState = useStore().getState()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (appState.loggedIn) {
      navigation.replace('Application')
    }

    setLoading(false)
  }, [])

  if (loading) return <LoadingScreen />

  return <YOUR_COMPONENT>

}
```

I hope this helps  you get some ideas.